# Pass custom field value in to apex class

Tags: apex, trigger, custom-field

I have an object called 'Application__c' and field in that called 'Customer_Id__c'.

I need to pass the Customer_Id__c to apex class whenever user enter the data in the object.

[image]

Apex class

```
public static void passvalue()
    {
        String getcusid; 
        Loan_Application__c lapp = new  Loan_Application__c();
         getcusid=lapp.Saltedge_Customer_Id__c; 
        System.debug('customerid from sf' +getcusid);
    }
```

By record id I wish to pass the customer_id__c into apex class.
Any Idea.

[image]

Trigger to get the customer id data whenever user given.

Comment: What have you tried? Where are you stuck? There's not enough information here to offer suggestions. Please [edit] your post to add details.

Comment: @DavidReed, Can you able to follow what I'm try to convey?

Comment: Here's the Trailhead section on Apex triggers: https://trailhead.salesforce.com/content/learn/modules/apex_triggers

Answer (score 1):

This code is not an Apex trigger, and in fact doesn't do anything.

```
    Loan_Application__c lapp = new  Loan_Application__c();
     getcusid=lapp.Saltedge_Customer_Id__c;
```

Creating a new `Loan_Application__c` instance does not have any relationship to user interaction. No data will be populated there.

I would recommend completing the following Trailhead modules to start learning how to build Apex-based automation:

- [Apex Basics & Database](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/en/content/learn/modules/apex_database)
- [Apex Triggers](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/en/content/learn/modules/apex_triggers)